# Django SyntaxError at / Non-ASCII character '\xe6' in file

Tags: python, django

I am getting this error:

```
SyntaxError at /
Non-ASCII character '\xe6' in file
```

pointed to my `forms.py` file which has some chinese characters

I have to put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the start the `forms.py` file before it would work

I thought Django handles everything in unicode? What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. You have done the correct thing. If you want to use non-ASCII characters in your code, you need to tell Python what encoding you are using.

This has nothing to do with Django, or Unicode.